# Need to get the Id of a selected item in a spinner from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

im a newbie to android and i have this problem here hope you guys can help me with this :)
anyways, i want to get the id of a selected item in the spinner from sqlite database so that i can save it to another table later on.
here's my code:

in my DB.java :

```
public List<String> getSemesterList() {
     List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SEMESTER;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                List.add((c.getString(1)));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return List;
}
public String getSemesterId() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_SEMESTER_ID, KEY_SEMESTER };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_SEMESTER, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);      

    int id = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEMESTER_ID);


    String semId = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        semId   = semId  + c.getInt(id) + " " 
                + "\n";
    }

    return semId ;
}
```

and in my createSYAttended.class

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DB entry = new DB(this);
    entry.open();
    final List<String> all = entry.getSemesterList();
        if(all.size()>0) // check if list contains items.
        {    
        sqlSem = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sprSemester);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateSyAttended.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, all);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    sqlSem.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    entry.close();


  sqlSem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});  
   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a mapping for the index of your `List<String> all = entry.getSemesterList();` to the spinner item

so when you get below callback

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
```

you can then use the position you get in the callback to map to the item in the `semesterList` `all`